# RabbitMQ management - 404 when loading a queue or exchange

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, rabbitmq, google-kubernetes-engine

I have installed RabbitMQ to my Kubernetes Cluster via Google Cloud Platform's marketplace.

I can connect to it fine in my other applications hosted in the Kubernetes Cluster, I can create queues and setup consumers from them without any problems too.

I can temporarily port forward port 15672 so that I can access the management user interface from my machine. I can login fine and I get a list of queues and exchanges when visiting their pages. But as soon as I select a queue or an exchange to load that specific item, I get a 404 response and the following message. I get them same when trying to add a new queue.

```
Not found
The object you clicked on was not found; it may have been deleted on the server.
```

They definitely exist, because when I go back to the listing page, they're there. It's really frustrating as it would be nice to test my microservices by simply publishing a message to a queue using RabbitMQ management, but I'm currently blocked from doing so!

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

**Edit**
A screenshot provided for clarity (after clicking the queue in the list):
[image: rabbitmq admin]

If I try to add a new queue, I don't get that message, instead I get a 405.

Comment: When you say "port forward" do you mean from a container or through a proxy? I would be very curious to know what is shown by the "Network" trace dev tool in your web browser.

Comment: Can you provide screenshots perhaps?

Comment: @LukeBakken I'm using gcloud console and running kubectl port-forward -etc.

Comment: @AhmetB-Google I've added a screenshot now

Comment: @AhmetB-Google it's easily reproducible. If you go to the GCP MarketPlace, configure RabbitMQ for Kubernetes, then go to Kubernetes Engine / Services / RabbitMQName-svc, then click Port Forwarding on port 15672. Open the link generated, then try either selecting a queue / exchange or adding a new queue / exchange.

Comment: @ThePower I have got the same issue. I configured RMQ server in ubuntu 16.04. RMQ admin portal is working fine .  after proxy pass with 15672, the above error is throwing. Any suggestions with sample proxy.

Comment: @LloydPowell Have you solved the issue?

Comment: @KoopaKiller I didn't directly, but I've since decided that anything that needs to persist in any shape or form that I would run it outside of my kubernetes cluster. So that's how I resolved that one. Sorry if that answer isn't so great, but it lead me to a change in architectural decision making and to consider service bus the same as I do with databases and storage.

Comment: @LloydPowell I totally understand your decision. I will try to play around with it and if I find something I'll here. Thanks for answer!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem as you this morning, and I fix it by using the bellow configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name rabbitmq.o2c.ovh;
    access_log acces.log;
    error_log error.log;
    location / {
        client_body_buffer_size 128k;
        proxy_send_timeout   90;
        proxy_read_timeout   90;
        proxy_buffer_size    4k;
        proxy_buffers     16 32k;
        proxy_busy_buffers_size 64k;
        proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
        proxy_connect_timeout 30s;
        proxy_pass   http://localhost:15672;
        proxy_set_header   Host   $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is because the default virtual-host is '/'. RabbitMQ admin uses this in the URL when you access the exchanges/queues pages. URL encoded it becomes '%2F'. However, the Ingress Controller (in my case nginx) converts that back to '/' so the admin app can't find that URL (hence the 404).

The work-around I came up with was to change the **default_vhost** setting in rabbitmq to something without '/' in it (e.g. 'vhost').

In the bitnami rabbitmq [Helm chart](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/rabbitmq) I'm using, this is configured using:

```
rabbitmq:
  extraConfiguration: |-
    default_vhost = vhost
```

You do have to update your clients to explicitly specify this new virtual-host though as they generally default to using '/'. In Spring Boot this is as simple as adding:

```
spring:
  rabbitmq:
    virtual-host: vhost
```

Answer (score 0):

Check with internal URL it should work as expected, otherwise your `definitions.json` will be not reachable by your `.yml` file.